# Conditional Formatting script issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm using an onEdit script whitch moves the entire row with chexbox to an other sheet and reverse.
When I try to apply Conditional Formatting rules with my custom formula whitch looks like this : `='New'!$D:$D="valueX"`

Everything is OK until I move entire row via script.  When I move the row back to the first sheet the Conditional formatting formula changes and excludes the current row from the original formula. It looks like this :

| Original Formula | Formula after the move |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Original Formula] | [image] |

So I came up with an idea to add some lines to my script

Final script looks like this :

```
function onEdit(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  if (r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart != 1) return;
  let dest;
  if (src.getName() == "New")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
  else if (src.getName() == "Complete")
    dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("New");  
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,10).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange("D2:D");
   var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenTextEqualTo("Low")
.setBackground("#00FF00")
.setRanges([range])
.build();

   var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenTextEqualTo("Medium")
.setBackground("#FFFF00")
.setRanges([range])
.build();

   var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenTextEqualTo("High")
.setBackground("#FF0000")
.setRanges([range])
.build();

var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
rules.push(rule1);
rules.push(rule2);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  }
```

Moving rows with checkbox works perfectly but the Conditional Formatting doesnt work and I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) (the "Range" method), this should copy the content as well as any relevant conditional formatting.